# How do I set {argslist} programmatically in vim?

Tags: vim

I know I can set the list of files like this:

```
:args file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

I would like to set args based on a command.  I also know, if I used a fresh vim, I could do this:

```
vim $(some-command)
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
:argsexpr system('some-command')
```

Like how `:cexpr` and `:lexpr` work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no argexpr command. However you can do it like this:

```
:argadd `some-command`
```

which runs some-command and adds the result to the argument list.